# Can I add my HTML page as a browser home page?

Tags: html

I am having HTML file in my desktop, how can i add my HTML page as browser home page and how can i add.

Comment: this is not a programming question, I think.

Comment: tagged javascript...haha...nice joke..

Comment: Google has some [answers](http://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr#q=how+to+add+a+web+page+as+homepage+in+browser&spell=1&sa=X&ei=mVH7UdnUE4LirAenvoDACg&ved=0CCcQBSgA&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&fp=221d55d00cd2fdba&biw=1024&bih=667&bvm=pv.xjs.s.en_US.seW1cfrvSKg.O) for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open your file in browser. copy address of your file from browser. So For example in internet explorer:

click setting button->Internet Options. In Home page section click **use current** button
and paste addrress to the cell. Address must be like this:

file:///C:/Users/user/Desktop/test.html

In chrome Settings->On startup->click set page-> in the dialog box past address. And so on :)

Answer (score 0):

Load the file into your browser (double click on the html file), and then use the browser menus select this as your homepage.

Answer (score 0):

Try @ the links hope u find your answer
https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/463?hl=en
Or
http://techlans.com/2013/04/how-to-set-your-own-image-in-firefox-browser-homepage.html